# Не работает скролл бар

Tags: css

Хочу сделать чтобы скрол бар был спрятан , но возможность прокручивать список осталась ?

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.chat {
  width: 46.2963vh;
  margin-left: 1.2963vh;
  margin-top: 1.48148vh;
}

.chat__allmesages {
  height: 35.83333vh;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 0.92593vh;
}

.chat__mesage {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 0.74074vh;
  padding: 0.37037vh 0.55556vh 0.37037vh 0.46296vh;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.38889vh;
  line-height: 1.94444vh;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 0.46296vh;
  word-break: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
         <ul class="chat__allmesages">
            <li class="chat__mesage">
              <p>привет</p>
            </li>
            <li class="chat__mesage">
              <p>привет</p>
            </li>
            <li class="chat__mesage">
              <p>привет</p>
            </li>
            <li class="chat__mesage">
              <p>привет</p>
            </li>
            <li class="chat__mesage">
              <p>привет</p>
            </li>
            <li class="chat__mesage">
              <p>привет</p>
            </li>
            <li class="chat__mesage">
              <p>привет</p>
            </li>
            <li class="chat__mesage">
              <p>привет</p>
            </li>
            <li class="chat__mesage">
              <p>привет</p>
            </li>
            <li class="chat__mesage">
              <p>привет</p>
            </li>
            <li class="chat__mesage">
              <p>привет</p>
            </li>
         </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
}
```

Comment: только в webkit'овских движках и будет работать

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
} Не работает